# Dynamic Language Runtime and CLR - what's the point of DLR?

Tags: .net

From wikipedia's entry on [DLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Language_Runtime),

it look like the purpose of DLR is for using language like Python, Ruby...etc. Is that all to DLR? Is there any other benefits and why do you want to pick IronPython over C# for say ASP.net project or Winform app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CLR and its underlying execution model is optimized for statically typed languages. Pretty much all the methods in the class libraries with .NET take arguments that are more precisely typed than the root of the type system, System.Object.

Dynamically typed languages require a different set of functionality in a runtime. They need the ability to efficiently execute dynamically typed code. For example, when a dynamically typed language calls a regular CLR class, it needs to convert and / or typecast each argument to the statically-defined type on the CLR class. If this isn't done carefully, it can be inefficient.

Similarly, dynamically typed languages often have an object model which isn't easily mappable to the CLR class model with explicitly typed properties, methods, fields etc. Instead, objects are often more like hashtables, buckets of key-value pairs where the keys are strings (or symbols) and the values are methods, closures, or object values themselves. The objects (and / or their types) are often extensible at runtime as well.

Since there are similarities between the dynamically typed languages, it would be useful for the commonality to be extracted out into a base set of functionality, to ease both interoperation and dynamic language implementation, as well as making it easier for CLR optimizations to be specifically focused on dynamic languages. The new `dynamic` keyword in C# is part of this: it uses mechanisms from the DLR to help interoperate with dynamically typed languages and object systems, such as COM automation objects, IronPython, IronRuby, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The DLR is incredibly powerful and useful. For example with the DLR you can execute any arbitrary Ruby or Python script in an application written in C#. There are lots of other usage scenarios but the dynamic script hosting has so far been the most useful one for me.

Answer (score 1):

It gives developers more options and flexibility for using the .NET CLR and all of its functionality.  You can use the language that you know best, or the language that is best suited to the task at hand, whether that's C#, F#, Ruby, or whatever.

Comment: +1 Instead of forcing you to learn C#, VB.net - you can continue to leverage your expertise in any of the dynamic languages like Ruby or Python and still be productive. The fact that it is actually the CLR that is executing your code becomes a opaque technical detail.

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever get tired of writing

```
string firstName = (string)Session["FirstName"];
```

With the DLR, you could simply write

```
dynamic firstName = Session.FirstName;
```

Comment: Thats not the DLR per-se its a new C# feature.

Comment: No I don't and in my opinion this is yet another feature to be avoided. I rather have the firt line of code because it is way more explicit, and I'm a fan of clean code. As for this DLR, we already have pattens like Adapter, Provider, and so one, to deal with this kind of issues. Creating a contract as an interface and having a library providing wrappers to call environment outside of the CLR world is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The new C# will use some of the features in DLR. new constructs and language elements are commng...